# Drawing a chessboard with unicode characters

Tags: interface, command-line

Wondering the best unicode characters to draw a chessboard... particularly the right combination of square and row/col delimiters (if any) to give a readable layout in a terminal window.  Here's what I have so far ... somehow this looks really "busy" to me.

[image]

Any idea of how to improve it so that the eye can easily follow the movement?

Would like the tags "chess" and "unicode", but unfortunately don't have the rep.

Comment: Is there some reason that you are restricted to outputting this in a terminal?

Comment: @JohnGB yes -- that's by design; nevertheless, unicode is unicode, right?

Comment: Is it possible to change the colour of certain terminal characters?

Comment: I'm going to use NCurses after I get the basic structure of the board down, so yes, there can be color applied to a single character or range of characters.  I plan on using this color capability to track things like the last move, player turn, etc.

Comment: @g33kz0r - then I would experiment by reducing the luminosity of the lines.

Comment: @Mervin just wondering what about this question makes it "too localized". If this is being discussed on at least one other page on the internet, and commented on by a bunch of people (see the daniweb article), then how is not applicable to the worldwide audience of the Internet?

Answer (score 3):

The guy here has written a python code to generate the chessboard using unicode characters. You may want to use the same characters for the board - they make a full square.

Hope this helps!

[Python code to generate unicode chess](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/423640/unicode-chessboard-in-a-terminal)

Comment: The image in my question was also generated using python :)  My question is not "how do I draw a chessboard in unicode" (I've already done that) but rather, "what are the most visually appealing or best looking unicode line characters to draw said board".

Comment: yes, I do understand that. My point was that the guy who wrote that code used a different set of unicode characters than yours and they are more visually appealing. Refer to the screenshot attached in the second comment in the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any unicode characters to draw the board itself.
One of the main characteristics of a chess board is the **black & white pattern**, right?

You should add that pattern as a background instead of those lines.  Especially those vertical lines makes the picture a mess.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The OP wants to do this with a terminal and unicode.  How does this apply?

Comment: If it's possible to set the background, then it's better to focus on this, than to try to draw those lines.

Comment: Is that comic sans?

Comment: @g33kz0r Ouch... :-P ...  I think it is...  Well, those chars/numbers aren't important, though.  Is it possible for you to change background color in your terminal solution?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit the problem with the approach you suggested (focus on the squares instead of the lines) is that you only have 2 piece colors to work with.

Comment: @g33, I don't see the problem?  You have black and white (i.e. outlined) pieces, and you have a white and gray board.  It's quite essential in chess to have the black and white "chess pattern" on the board.  If you [google chess board images](https://www.google.com/search?q=chess+board+images&hl=no&hs=vjr&tbm=isch), you'll find lots of monochrome solutions.  I would even argue that it's more important with this chess background than the glyphs. I'm pretty sure most chess players would be fine with letters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece#Piece_names).

Comment: My point is that terminal backgrounds are generally black or white.  This means that black pieces are solid inverse, and white pieces have an inverse outline that lets the background shine through.  If you change the color of a cell, you're also changing the color of the black pieces...

Comment: @g33, I still don't see the problem, here?  You don't need to use inverse glyphs.  Didn't you take a look at the examples I referred to?  Perhaps this 1k JS demo will help: http://js1k.com/2010-first/demo/435